# How to use the compare framework of eclipse to compare new content type?

Tags: eclipse, compare

I have to do an enhancement to an eclipse application and create a diff-viewer which compares two files(.blx) format. But, the application as such doesn't have the org.eclipse.compare bundle in its target platform. Now, if I include the bundle, the option Compare With comes with any pair of selections.

So, Instead of using extension points, I included the source of org.eclipse.compare in my plugin. But, Now I don't know if I should also create the extension points and use the same.
I am unable to create the structure compare pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in for a fair amount of work (I'm working on a similar thing now). Start with the [Compare documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/compare.htm) and read it carefully. Depending on how close what you are doing is to a text compare, you might be able to get away with simply subclassing things and using the extension points. However, if you have other requirements (non-textual) then it's likely that you will need to copy some of the code.

I don't recommend that you use the source of the plugin directly however. Just make sure you add it to your application as a dependency.

Comment: Is there any introduction to working with the compare library? I've spent the last week looking through indigo documentation, SO and egit and eclipse source code trying to figure out how to implement my own comparison view, and can't find anything to get me going

Comment: A useful resource is the presentation ["ABCs Of Platform Workspace"](https://www.eclipsecon.org/2008/sub/attachments/ABC_of_Platform_Workspace.ppt) from EclipseCon 2008 by Szymon Brandys and Tomasz Zarna.